# change string in DF using hive command and mutate with sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, gsub, sparklyr

Using the Hive command `regexp_extract` I am trying to change the following strings from:

```
201703170455 to 2017-03-17:04:55
```

and from:

```
2017031704555675 to 2017-03-17:04:55.0010
```

I am doing this in sparklyr trying to use this code that works with gsub in R:

```
  newdf<-df%>%mutate(Time1 = regexp_extract(Time, "(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)", "\\1-\\2-\\3:\\4:\\5"))
```

and this code:

```
newdf<-df%>mutate(TimeTrans = regexp_extract("(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(....)", "\\1-\\2-\\3:\\4:\\5.\\6"))
```

but does not work at all. Any suggestions of how to do this using regexp_extract?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache Spark uses Java regular expression dialect not R, and groups should be referenced with `$`. Furthermore `regexp_replace` is used to [extract a single group by a numeric index](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_extract(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp:String,groupIdx:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

You can use `regexp_replace`:

```
df <- data.frame(time = c("201703170455", "2017031704555675"))
sdf <- copy_to(sc, df)

sdf %>% 
  mutate(time1 = regexp_replace(
    time, "^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)$", "$1-$2-$3 $4:$5" )) %>%
  mutate(time2 = regexp_replace(
    time, "^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(....)$", "$1-$2-$3 $4:$5.$6"))
```

```
Source:   query [2 x 3]
Database: spark connection master=local[8] app=sparklyr local=TRUE

# A tibble: 2 x 3
              time            time1                 time2
             <chr>            <chr>                 <chr>
1     201703170455 2017-03-17 04:55          201703170455
2 2017031704555675 2017031704555675 2017-03-17 04:55.5675
```