# Sparklyr/Hive: how to use regex (regexp_replace) correctly?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, sparklyr

Consider the following example

```
dataframe_test<- data_frame(mydate = c('2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z', '2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z'))

# A tibble: 2 x 1
                    mydate
                     <chr>
1 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z
2 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z

sdf <- copy_to(sc, dataframe_test, overwrite = TRUE)

> sdf
# Source:   table<dataframe_test> [?? x 1]
# Database: spark_connection
                    mydate
                     <chr>
1 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z
2 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z
```

I would like to modify the character `timestamp` so that it has a more conventional format. I tried to do so using `regexp_replace` but it fails.

```
> sdf <- sdf %>% mutate(regex = regexp_replace(mydate, '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})T(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}).(\\d{3})Z', '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7'))
> sdf
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_connection
                    mydate                    regex
                     <chr>                    <chr>
1 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z
2 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z
```

Any ideas? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: The pattern is correct (you could use literal `.` in place of wildcard), you're just using a wrong function.

Comment: wait a sec, please. which function should I use? your link actually specifies the same function I use

Comment: Take a closer look - it is `regexp_replace`, not `regexp_extract` :)

Comment: woooooooooooooooooooooot !!!

Comment: actually it still does not work... let me update the question. but thanks for the catch!!!!

Comment: done. can you please have a look again @zero323 ? thanks!!

Comment: @zero323 can you please re-open?

Comment: I believe this is still a duplicate - I was just wrong about the pattern. Please note that it has to match a whole string and you didn't escape everything: `sdf %>% mutate(regex = regexp_replace(mydate, '^(\\\\d{4})-(\\\\d{2})-(\\\\d{2})T(\\\\d{2}):(\\\\d{2}):(\\\\d{2}).(\\\\d{3})Z$', '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7'))`. You could use `regexp_extact`, but it would require enumerating all fields `sdf %>% mutate(regex = regexp_extract(mydate, '^(\\\\d{4})-(\\\\d{2})-(\\\\d{2})T(\\\\d{2}):(\\\\d{2}):(\\\\d{2}).(\\\\d{3})Z$', 1))`

Comment: argh that works now. well in that case I think this is an interesting answer. why do I need to escape twice? the official documentation says `\d` needs to be written `\\d`. Instead you suggest I should escape even more. why is that?

Comment: You have to escape once for R and once for Java I am afraid. If you think this should be a separate answer, I can reopen it.

Comment: yes, I think this is a very useful answer. Nobody knows that you need to combine the escapes. one for each language ! :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark SQL and Hive provide two different functions:

- `regexp_extract` - which takes string, pattern and the index of the group to be extracted.
- `regexp_replace` - which takes a string, pattern, and the replacement string.

The former one can be used to extract **a single group** with the index semantics [being the same](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) as for [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

For `regexp_replace` pattern has to match a whole string and if there is no match, and the input string is returned:

```
sdf %>% mutate(
 regex = regexp_replace(mydate, '^([0-9]{4}).*', "$1"),
 regexp_bad = regexp_replace(mydate, '([0-9]{4})', "$1"))

## Source:   query [2 x 3]
## Database: spark connection master=local[8] app=sparklyr local=TRUE
## 
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##                     mydate regex               regexp_bad
##                      <chr> <chr>                    <chr>
## 1 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z  2011 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z
## 2 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z  2011 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z
```

while with `regexp_extract` it is not required:

```
sdf %>% mutate(regex = regexp_extract(mydate, '([0-9]{4})', 1))

## Source:   query [2 x 2]
## Database: spark connection master=local[8] app=sparklyr local=TRUE
## 
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##                     mydate regex
##                      <chr> <chr>
## 1 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z  2011
## 2 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z  2011
```

Also, due to indirect execution (R -> Java), you have to escape twice:

```
sdf %>% mutate(
  regex = regexp_replace(
    mydate, 
    '^(\\\\d{4})-(\\\\d{2})-(\\\\d{2})T(\\\\d{2}):(\\\\d{2}):(\\\\d{2}).(\\\\d{3})Z$',
    '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7'))
```

Normally one would use Spark datetime functions:

```
spark_session(sc) %>%  
  invoke("sql",
    "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(CAST(mydate AS timestamp), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') parsed from dataframe_test") %>% 
  sdf_register


## Source:   query [2 x 2]
## Database: spark connection master=local[8] app=sparklyr local=TRUE
## 
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##                     mydate                  parsed
##                      <chr>                   <chr>
## 1 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z 2011-03-01 01:00:04.226
## 2 2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z 2011-03-01 01:00:04.226
```

but sadly `sparklyr` seems to be extremely limited in this area, and treats timestamps as strings.

See also [change string in DF using hive command and mutate with sparklyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44336295/1560062).

Comment: really interesting solution

Answer (score 3):

I had some difficulties to replace "." with "", but finally it works with:

```
mutate(myvar2=regexp_replace(myvar, "[.]", ""))
```