# sparklyr dataframe : replace NULL cell by NA - How to use gsub & regex for spark DF?

Tags: r, na, substitution, is-empty, sparklyr

How can I use `gsub` and `regex` into spark dataframe? 
This running example works well with classic DF.

```
## function to replace empty cell by NA
empty_as_na <- function(x){
  if("factor" %in% class(x)) x <- as.character(x)
  ifelse(as.character(x)!="", x, NA)
}

## connect to spark local
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

# load an example of dataframe that has empty cells (needs cgdsr package)

clinicalData <- cgdsr::getClinicalData(cgds, "gbm_tcga_pub_all")

## copy to spark
clinicalData_tbl <- dplyr::copy_to(sc, clinicalData, overwrite = TRUE)

 # It works for classic dataframe
clinicalData %>% mutate_all(funs(empty_as_na))

# It does not work for Spark DF
clinicalData_tbl %>% mutate_all(funs(empty_as_na))
```

Referring to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658852/sparklyr-hive-how-to-use-regex-regexp-replace-correctly), I can substitute patterns by columns. I need to know in advance which column I have to proceed.
here a head of dataframe

```
clinicalData <- structure(list(Patients = structure(c(187L, 63L, 167L, 88L, 173L, 
                                              139L), .Label = c("TCGA.02.0001.01", "TCGA.02.0003.01", "TCGA.02.0004.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0006.01", "TCGA.02.0007.01", "TCGA.02.0009.01", "TCGA.02.0010.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0011.01", "TCGA.02.0014.01", "TCGA.02.0015.01", "TCGA.02.0016.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0021.01", "TCGA.02.0023.01", "TCGA.02.0024.01", "TCGA.02.0025.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0026.01", "TCGA.02.0027.01", "TCGA.02.0028.01", "TCGA.02.0033.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0034.01", "TCGA.02.0037.01", "TCGA.02.0038.01", "TCGA.02.0039.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0043.01", "TCGA.02.0046.01", "TCGA.02.0047.01", "TCGA.02.0048.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0052.01", "TCGA.02.0054.01", "TCGA.02.0055.01", "TCGA.02.0057.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0058.01", "TCGA.02.0060.01", "TCGA.02.0064.01", "TCGA.02.0068.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0069.01", "TCGA.02.0070.01", "TCGA.02.0071.01", "TCGA.02.0074.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0075.01", "TCGA.02.0079.01", "TCGA.02.0080.01", "TCGA.02.0083.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0084.01", "TCGA.02.0085.01", "TCGA.02.0086.01", "TCGA.02.0087.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0089.01", "TCGA.02.0099.01", "TCGA.02.0102.01", "TCGA.02.0104.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0106.01", "TCGA.02.0107.01", "TCGA.02.0111.01", "TCGA.02.0113.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0114.01", "TCGA.02.0115.01", "TCGA.02.0116.01", "TCGA.02.0258.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0260.01", "TCGA.02.0266.01", "TCGA.02.0269.01", "TCGA.02.0271.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0281.01", "TCGA.02.0285.01", "TCGA.02.0289.01", "TCGA.02.0290.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0317.01", "TCGA.02.0321.01", "TCGA.02.0324.01", "TCGA.02.0325.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0326.01", "TCGA.02.0330.01", "TCGA.02.0332.01", "TCGA.02.0333.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0337.01", "TCGA.02.0338.01", "TCGA.02.0339.01", "TCGA.02.0422.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0430.01", "TCGA.02.0432.01", "TCGA.02.0439.01", "TCGA.02.0440.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.02.0446.01", "TCGA.02.0451.01", "TCGA.02.0456.01", "TCGA.06.0122.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0124.01", "TCGA.06.0125.01", "TCGA.06.0126.01", "TCGA.06.0127.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0128.01", "TCGA.06.0129.01", "TCGA.06.0130.01", "TCGA.06.0132.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0133.01", "TCGA.06.0137.01", "TCGA.06.0138.01", "TCGA.06.0139.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0141.01", "TCGA.06.0143.01", "TCGA.06.0145.01", "TCGA.06.0146.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0147.01", "TCGA.06.0148.01", "TCGA.06.0149.01", "TCGA.06.0152.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0154.01", "TCGA.06.0156.01", "TCGA.06.0157.01", "TCGA.06.0158.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0162.01", "TCGA.06.0164.01", "TCGA.06.0166.01", "TCGA.06.0168.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0169.01", "TCGA.06.0171.01", "TCGA.06.0173.01", "TCGA.06.0174.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0175.01", "TCGA.06.0176.01", "TCGA.06.0177.01", "TCGA.06.0178.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0179.01", "TCGA.06.0182.01", "TCGA.06.0184.01", "TCGA.06.0185.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0187.01", "TCGA.06.0188.01", "TCGA.06.0189.01", "TCGA.06.0190.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0194.01", "TCGA.06.0195.01", "TCGA.06.0197.01", "TCGA.06.0201.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0206.01", "TCGA.06.0208.01", "TCGA.06.0209.01", "TCGA.06.0210.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0211.01", "TCGA.06.0213.01", "TCGA.06.0214.01", "TCGA.06.0219.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0221.01", "TCGA.06.0237.01", "TCGA.06.0238.01", "TCGA.06.0241.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0394.01", "TCGA.06.0397.01", "TCGA.06.0402.01", "TCGA.06.0409.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0410.01", "TCGA.06.0412.01", "TCGA.06.0413.01", "TCGA.06.0414.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.06.0644.01", "TCGA.06.0645.01", "TCGA.06.0646.01", "TCGA.06.0648.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0244.01", "TCGA.08.0246.01", "TCGA.08.0344.01", "TCGA.08.0345.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0346.01", "TCGA.08.0347.01", "TCGA.08.0348.01", "TCGA.08.0349.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0350.01", "TCGA.08.0351.01", "TCGA.08.0352.01", "TCGA.08.0353.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0354.01", "TCGA.08.0355.01", "TCGA.08.0356.01", "TCGA.08.0357.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0358.01", "TCGA.08.0359.01", "TCGA.08.0360.01", "TCGA.08.0373.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0375.01", "TCGA.08.0380.01", "TCGA.08.0385.01", "TCGA.08.0386.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0389.01", "TCGA.08.0390.01", "TCGA.08.0392.01", "TCGA.08.0509.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0510.01", "TCGA.08.0511.01", "TCGA.08.0512.01", "TCGA.08.0514.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0516.01", "TCGA.08.0517.01", "TCGA.08.0518.01", "TCGA.08.0520.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0521.01", "TCGA.08.0522.01", "TCGA.08.0524.01", "TCGA.08.0525.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.08.0529.01", "TCGA.08.0531.01", "TCGA.12.0615.01", "TCGA.12.0616.01", 
                                                                "TCGA.12.0618.01", "TCGA.12.0619.01", "TCGA.12.0620.01"), class = "factor"), 
                       ACGH_DATA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NO", 
                                                                                   "YES"), class = "factor"), CANCER_TYPE = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Glioma", class = "factor"), 
                       CANCER_TYPE_DETAILED = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
                       ), .Label = "Glioblastoma Multiforme", class = "factor"), 
                       COMPLETE_DATA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NO", 
                                                                                       "YES"), class = "factor"), DFS_MONTHS = c(NA, NA, 3.024657534, 
                                                                                                                                 NA, 17.0630137, 2.202739726), DFS_STATUS = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "DiseaseFree", "Recurred"
                                                                                                                                                                                        ), class = "factor"), FRACTION_GENOME_ALTERED = c(0.168880099, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.126393857, 0.254657044, 0.174506086, 0.182024694, 0.154967319
                                                                                                                                                                                        ), KARNOFSKY_PERFORMANCE_SCORE = c(60L, NA, NA, NA, 100L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA), MRNA_DATA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NO", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "YES"), class = "factor"), MUTATION_COUNT = c(NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          4L, NA, 0L), ONCOTREE_CODE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 1L), .Label = "GBM", class = "factor"), OS_MONTHS = c(12.55890411, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             14.46575342, 9.797260274, 20.35068493, 24.55890411, 7.397260274
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ), OS_STATUS = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("DECEASED", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "LIVING"), class = "factor"), PRETREATMENT_HISTORY = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NO", "YES"), class = "factor"), 
                       PRIOR_GLIOMA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NO", 
                                                                                      "YES"), class = "factor"), SEQUENCED = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NO", "YES"), class = "factor"), 
                       SEX = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", 
                                                                             "Male"), class = "factor"), TREATMENT_STATUS = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Treated", "Untreated"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and than

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

clinicalData_tbl <- dplyr::copy_to(sc, clinicalData, overwrite = TRUE)

clinicalData_tbl %>%
mutate(DFS_STATUS=regexp_replace(DFS_STATUS, "^$|^ $", "NA"))
```

I tried with NA , without `""`, but does not work.

Comment: When you say "it works" for classic dataframe, I suspect you are looking at the console output. That code did not, however, make any change to `clinicalData` since no assignment was made. So I'm guessing there might be a similar issue facing attempts at database manipulation.

Comment: Why don't you apply `mutate_all` before you load it into a spark table?

Comment: @wp78de I would like to distribute pre-processing steps to spark nodes.